# Why do I get a warning about JSX when I do not use JSX?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a Vue.js component file (the framework is Quasar) where, in `<template>` I have the following block of code:

```html
<q-btn
 color="green"
 label="save & continue editing"
 @click="saveCase()"
/>
```

It is part of other code.

This code is highlighted as an error by TypeScript:

[image]

Details of the error:

```
[{
    "resource": "/D:/dev-pro/secops-cases/front/src/components/Case.vue",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "17004",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 108,
    "startColumn": 11,
    "endLineNumber": 112,
    "endColumn": 13
}]
```

What does it mean? I do not use React at all, just Vue.js, Quasar and TypeScript. `<q-btn>` is the only element that is highlighted as errornous, any other element (generic or Quasar) is fine.

Comment: How exactly is it highlighted? It's not evident that the error refers to this element.

Comment: @EstusFlask: I added an image of vscode - with a piece of code specific to Quasar (`q-input`) to show that  the error is localized to `q-btn`

Comment: @WoJ did you tell your IDE you are coding vue.js?

Comment: @Voidy: yes, and everything else is fine (including all Vue3 specificities). It is just that single element that is highlighted as an error (an the app works)

Comment: Unless you have the same error when running the app, the question shouldn't be asked in general. It's IDE-specific. All tools (bundler, linter, ide, etc) implement differently the way they work with a toolchain in use, and they often behave differently. This is most likely the case here.

Comment: Try to add the closing tag like `<q-btn ...></q-btn>`

Comment: It's some kind of bug because `<script lang="ts">` 
Maybe this issue will explain the reason: https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/1431

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: this did the trick. I do not know what but now there is no more warning related to JSX. Would you mind making an answer out of your comment so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @WoJ I get the reason behind this issue please check my edited answer

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim oh - thank you very much for the follow-up. Your solution to close the tag was working, now I know why. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a closing tag to avoid this warning :

```html
<q-btn
 color="green"
 label="save & continue editing"
 @click="saveCase()"
></q-btn>
```

This issue can be avoided also by adding `"jsx": "preserve",` to the `compilerOptions` entry in `tsconfig.json` file :

```
{
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
  }
}
```